# I want a db2 query to which satisfy the following condition

Tags: java, db2

I have requirement to fetch all the rows which have value in some column like d'souza or in the form of something'something i tried using a **like** query as '[a-zA-Z]''%' but its not working. please need your help

Answer (score 1):

Try LIKE with '%''%'

Sadly SQL's LIKE statement doesn't offer advanced RegEx functionality (Though that might be different for db2). But after you've filtered your results like that, you can do the fine-grained checking by using a script or as part of your application.

**[EDIT]**
As you wrote that you have restrictions regarding the % sign at the beginning of the statement you could try something complicated like:

'a''%' OR 'b''%' OR ... 'A''%' OR 'B''%' ...

Not very beautiful code, but effective.

Comment: @GuruKulki: Why, doesn't it work for some records, please be more specific.

Comment: I have some restriction on using % at the beginning like your answer, which works perfectly but i cannot use.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for .kindly read the post.

**DB2** database,  **regexp** is not supported (without additional libraries).

[Emulate REGEXP like behaviour in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712132/emulate-regexp-like-behaviour-in-sql)